# Backend architecture for online boardgame-like site

Tags: django, architecture, redis, celery, tornado

Hello Stackoverflowers,

We're developing an online board-game (think online monopoly) site using Python for the backend.

We use Django for the non realtime stuff (authenticating, player profiles, ranking...). The chat server is implemented using socket.io and Tornodo. The game server part is what caused us problems.

We currently (that could change) also use Tornado and socket.io, each Tornado instance is located at a gameX.site.com address on a (maybe) different server and host several games simultaneously (much like a chat server in fact, except that messages would not go to all users but only to the ones involved in the same game).

What cause us trouble is how to we update the Django instance (game log, score, and so on) as games progress. Also we'd like to use Django for authentication as each player would ask the Django server to join the game and be given a disposable id/password couple just for it. Obviously we would have to communicate those to the game server in some way.

At first the chosen solution was to use something like Redis as a bidirectional message queue, Django would post is/password to Redis and the Tornado would then querying Redis on incoming connection. Also a Django cron would run every minute or so to deal with the waiting message. But we fear that frequently and possibly long running cron would impede the main site since the PostgreSQL database is hosted on the same server as Django (and some Game server may also run on the same machine).

We could alternatively wait for a player to request a ranking updated to process the past games results but we fear such an indefinite delay will skew the overall ranking (and experience) and would possibly cause data loss.

We could use Celery/RabbitMQ to update the Main database using Django ORM out of the Tornado processes, but would it be possible to use the same solution to communicate the temporary id/password to the game server ? It doesn't look like you can post a message to Celery and retrieve it on an other side.

Thank for your insight.

Comment: What is the problem? Maintaining the game state?

Comment: It seems I was clear (maybe a little bit too involved while writing). Anyway, we finally settled with a REST API for the django app (with tastypie) so the twisted client can update the django database with ease. I dunno If it's ok to let the question rot or if I should delete it. Anyway thank for your time Gustav !

Comment: @thomas could you please elaborate more over how you solve this problem? or contact me by email (its in my profile). We are a small startup and we are facing a similar problem, I would be really thankful if I could get some help from you.